# MicroData Headaches, Nesting, and Mixed up info

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-markup, microdata

I understand the majority of this topic and how to nest something like address vocabulary in person vocabulary.

but I'm wondering into more details for less straight forward pieces of info or "mixed up" info. Any Advice documentation is appreciated

So Couple Example Questions

1.) Is there no way to associate an email address that google understands? Maybe I missed this?

2.) Let's say John & Jane Sign the bottom of their Blog Together They both have the same site and affiliations, would using the name prop twice in one section of person be appropriate? would it associate that both John and Jane are two separate people both affiliations?

3.) Can more than one of any itemprop be used for example I have 3 affiliations and 3 titles, I don't want to write my name three times so i would use itemprop name and than title prop 3 separate times? furthermore how would i associate the title and role of the the three separate ones together?

4.) To take that farther what if Jane also had the Title of SEO where as John had the title of Music and Jane and John had the title of Web Development and both had the same URL how could more intertwined mark ups like this be represented without listing all the info for each person separately?

4.) Let's say you have an affiliation with company a and company b what would be the best method to also nest the business information for company a and company b ?

The Majority of my questions are along the same lines but I think nipping these or any documentation that covers scenarios similar to these would help clear up alot of confusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think most of this is possible with the current status of microdata. One way round it would be to add the info in another place (i.e. first person at the end of a post, then second person hidden at end of page), which semantically is stupid, but would allow naive parsing to pick up both cards.

As I say though, I don't think there is a neat way to do this in the page at the moment.

Comment: darn, well i guess Iw ill stick of calling myself my fiancee's "friend" and hope people atleast make the connection that I'm involved in all that junk. i would love to find out some sort of naming convention or schema where u can get quite detailed I'm not willing to go through the confusion of separating everything up :P

Comment: It might be worth asking on the working group email list, I believe that it's public-html@w3.org.

Comment: awesome I think I'll clean up my questions a bit into better examples and give them an email :)